# Cannot finish Game by pressing the Q key in my keyboard

Tags: python, pygame

I created a small game (currently working on that). Where I want to print out the key of a dictionary on the screen and pass to the next word after pressing the Space Bar. It works well, however, when I finished iterating over all keys, and press the Q button to exit the game, it does not make anything.

Here is my code:

```
import sys 
pygame.init() 
pygame.font.init() 

keywords  = {

            'auto': 'gives a local variable a local lifetime',
            'break': 'exits out of a compound statement',
            'case': 'a branch in a switch-statement',
            'char': 'a character data type',
            'const': 'makes a variable unmodifiable',
            'continue': 'continues to the top of a loop',
            'default': 'default branch in a switch-statement',
            'do': 'starts a do-while loop',
            'double': 'a double floating-point data type',
            'else': 'an else branch of an if-statement',
            'enum': 'defines a set of int constants',
            'extern': 'declares an identifier is defined externally',
            'float': 'a floating-point data type',
            'for': 'starts a for loop',
            'goto': 'jumps to a label',
            'if': 'starts an if statement',
            'int': 'an integer data type',
            'long': 'a long integer data type',
            'register': 'declares a variable be stored in a CPU register',
            'return': 'returns from a function',
            'short': 'a short integer data type',
            'signed': 'a signed modifier for integer data types',
            'sizeof': 'determines the size of the data',
            'static': 'preserves variable value after its scope exits',
            'struct': 'combine variables into a single record',
            'switch': 'starts a switch-statement',
            'typedef': 'creates a new type',
            'union': 'starts an union-statement',
            'unsigned': 'an unsigned modifier for integer data types',
            'void': 'declares a data type empty',
            'volatile': 'declares a variable might be modified elsewhere',
            'while': 'starts a while loop'

}



counter  = 0

size = (500, 700) 
screen = pygame.display.set_mode(size)
myfont = pygame.font.SysFont("Comic Sans MS", 30) 

while True:

    for event in pygame.event.get():

        if event.type == pygame.K_q:
            sys.exit()

        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_SPACE:
                try: 
                    counter += 1 
                    list_keys = list(keywords.keys()) 
                    screen.fill((255,255,255))
                    keyword = myfont.render(list_keys[counter], False, (0,0,0))
                    screen.blit(keyword, (200, 350))

                except IndexError: 
                    end_of_game_text = myfont.render("end of flashcards", False,(0,0,0))
                    screen.blit(end_of_game_text, (175, 325))


    pygame.display.flip()
```

Does it have to do with the position in which the key down event is set within the while loop? Does it have to go after the key down events?

I am working with python 2.7 and on Windows 10 as Operating system.

Answer (score 1):

`pygame.K_q` is not an even type (see [`pygame.event.EventType`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/event.html#pygame.event.EventType]), it is a key see ([`pygame.key`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/key.html)).
Verify if the event type is `pygame.KEYDOWN` (or `pygame.KEYUP`), then compare `event.key` to the <kbd>k</kbd> key (`pygame.K_q`). e.g:

```py
while True:

    for event in pygame.event.get():

        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:

            if event.key == pygame.K_q:
                sys.exit()

            elif event.key == pygame..K_SPACE:
                # [...]
```

Comment: OMG! Such detail! Thank you very much. That clarifies everything. Now it works